# Store id names in script

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

This is a question that I have wondered about for quite some time.

When I need to make a query that is for example as follows:

```
SELECT o.business_id, b.business_name, b.category 
FROM owner_tbl o 
INNER JOIN business_tbl b
WHERE o.user_id = 1
```

Imagine that I need to display the name of the business category (defined in the business_tbl) in Javascript at the client, and I know upfront that the number of categories will not change quickly.

I can prevent making an extra join with the `category_tbl` by storing the category names either:

- In an associative array in PHP;
- In an object in Javascript.

Would you consider this to be bad practice?
This type of situations often occurs: where you make a join, just to retrieve one 'name' field.

Is there any alternative way that avoids making a join to speed up the retrieval?

Comment: Since you will likely not have that many rows in your categories tables, just join without remorse. It will be fast enough. You might want to use indexes on your join criteria though.

Comment: If you join your both tables based on indexed columns then it will provide you better results..right now I am not seeing join columns in your query.

Comment: I did not make the join with the categories table yet in the example. As I wondered if it would be a viable solution to use a php array/javascript object to get the id labels. @ToBe mentioned that making the join will not really affect my performance, so I guess that I'll go for that solution.

Comment: Performance usually only is a concern if your tables have 100K+ rows or if you have 100+ page views per second. Depends on your hardware though, but you get the idea.

Comment: That's great, thanks. I was not sure about the cost of making the 'join' operation itself. I thought that this operation by itself could create some overhead.